# How to add Javascript when using Laravel Modules

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I am using [Laravel Modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules) in one of my applications and I have javascript files located in `Modules/module-name/Resources/assets/js`. How can I include this file to my view file, which is using Blade?

I tried using `{{ Module::asset('acl:js/user.js') }}`

But it is adding commented link only.

How to properly add the javascript files? I have javascript for most of the view files.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('Modules/ModuleName/Resources/assets/js/test.js')}}"></script>

Comment: @MdJuyelRana this approach doesn't work

Comment: I wonder who is downvoting this question after 3 years